# Angular recursive HTTP requests, combining responses, eventually returning single observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I would like to make recursive HTTP calls to a paginated API until I've gone through all the pages. Each page contains an array of assets which I will concatenate to a temporary array. Once I've read all pages I want to return a single array of all the assets as an observable.

I've been using a pipe with the expand operator. I notice I can print my final array on the completion of the subscription but I don't know how to elegantly return this array as an observable. Is there some way to wait for completion of one observable and then return another?

```js
getAllAssets(sort: string, filter: AssetFilter): Observable<Asset[]> {
  let allAssets: Asset[] = [];
  console.log('getAllAssets()', sort, filter);
  this._getAllAssets(null, null).subscribe((moreAssets) => {
    allAssets = allAssets.concat(moreAssets);
  }, null, () => console.log(allAssets));
  return of(allAssets);
}

_getAllAssets(sort: string, filter: AssetFilter) {
  let currentPage = 0;
  return this.getAssets(null, null, sort, filter).pipe(
    expand(assetsPage => {
      if (assetsPage && assetsPage.page.number + 1 < assetsPage.page.totalPages) {
        return this.getAssets(currentPage += 1, null, sort, filter);
      }
      return empty();
    }),
    map((value) => value._embedded.assets)
  );
}

getAssets(page: number, size: number, sort: string, filter: AssetFilter): Observable<Assets> {
  let url = 'https://gateway.' + environment.region + '.mindsphere.io/api/assetmanagement/v3/assets?';
  if (page) {
    url += 'page=' + page;
  }
  if (size) {
    url += 'size=' + size;
  }
  if (sort) {
    url += 'sort=' + sort;
  }
  if (filter) {
    url += 'filter=' + JSON.stringify(filter);
  }
  return this.http.get<Assets>(url, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken)
  });
}
```

I am getting the correct array printed to the screen but I'd like to return this array as an observable without having the create an observable, return the observable, and emit to it on completion.

EDIT:
My fix was to use `toArray()` as mentioned below. I then just did a map to turn the `Observable<item[][]>` into `Observable<item[]>`

```js
getAllAssets(sort: string, filter: AssetFilter): Observable<Asset[]> {
  let currentPage = 0;
  return this.getAssets(null, null, sort, filter).pipe(
    expand(assetsPage => {
      if (assetsPage && assetsPage.page.number + 1 < assetsPage.page.totalPages) {
        return this.getAssets((currentPage += 1), null, sort, filter);
      }
      return empty();
    }),
    map(value => value._embedded.assets),
    toArray()
  ).pipe(map(assets => [].concat.apply([], assets)));
}

getAssets(page: number, size: number, sort: string, filter: AssetFilter): Observable<Assets> {
  let url = 'https://gateway.' + environment.region + '.mindsphere.io/api/assetmanagement/v3/assets?';
  if (page) {
    url += 'page=' + page;
  }
  if (size) {
    url += 'size=' + size;
  }
  if (sort) {
    url += 'sort=' + sort;
  }
  if (filter) {
    url += 'filter=' + JSON.stringify(filter);
  }
  return this.http.get<Assets>(url, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a [`toArray`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/toArray/) operator

Heres an example with a `timer`

```js
timer(0, 5).pipe(
    take(3),
    toArray()
  )
```

[image: toArray]

Comment: This works great but what if I wanted to combine all of those arrays that are returned. This would make my function return  `Observable<Asset[][]>` but I want  `Observable<Asset[]>` with only a single array of all items.

Comment: @AustenStone then you could [`forkJoin`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) all observables that you need

Comment: `toArray` is to join all values on a stream into an array. `forkJoin` is to join last values on streams. Combine them as you need. **One important note**: try having only one subscription and put it at the end of the call chain. If its a service code you shared -- remove subscription from it, just pass through an observable chain.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of code to sift through so I'm going to reduce and generalize as it is a common pattern, this will take the form of:

```
   _getAllPages(page, constantArgs, lastSet) {
     lastSet = lastSet || []; // deal with entry
     return this.getPage(page, constantArgs).pipe( // fetch the page
        switchMap(res => 
          (res.nextPage) // if nextpage, recurse and concat to last set
             ? this._getAllPages(res.nextPage, lastSet.concat(res.items))
             : of(lastSet.concat(res.items)))); // else break
   }
```

for style purposes i'll usually have that be private and I'll have a public like:

```
getAllPages(constantArgs) {
  return this._getAllPages(0, constantArgs);
}
```

to make a better / easier to understand API.